# return value along with partial view ajax call in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on mvc4 project.I am using Dexexpress grid. What i want to do is when i click on add .. i do ajax call to check if user is in database..if not its saved into database and .. and i am returning paritial view of grid to refresh grid with latest data.

But i want to return some value too along with gridview partial.. so that i can show whther that user is already added or not.

Eg : Jquery code for ajax call

```
function AddUser() {
    showProgress();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ManageUsers/AddUsers/?id=' + Math.random(),
        data: $("#frmManageUsers").serialize(),
        type: 'Post',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != '') {                
                $("#grid").html('');
                $("#grid").html(data);
            }
            else
                alert('No Record Found');
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) { ShowErrorMessage(); },
        complete: function () { hideProgress(); ShowSuccessMessage(); }
    });
}
```

and controller

```
public ActionResult AddUsers(Usertable model)
        {
            int successid = ManageUserExecutor.Save(model);
            if (successid == -1)
            {
                List<usp_GetListOfUsers_Result> objList = new List<usp_GetListOfUsers_Result>();
                return PartialView("GridViewPartial", objList);
            }
            else
                return RedirectToAction("GridViewPartial");
        }
```

What i want is if i can get value of successid in ajax retrun along with gridview partial html ... so that i can display message according to that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the operation fails, simply return that as a JSON result:

```
public ActionResult AddUsers(Usertable model)
{
    int successid = ManageUserExecutor.Save(model);
    if (successid == -1)
    {
        List<usp_GetListOfUsers_Result> objList = new List<usp_GetListOfUsers_Result>();
        return PartialView("GridViewPartial", objList);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { id = successid });
    }
}
```

and your AJAX call:

```
function AddUser() {
    showProgress();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ManageUsers/AddUsers', // <!-- TODO: This url should NOT be hardcoded like that. It should be generated by a server side helper
        cache: false, // <!-- That's what should be used instead of reinventing wheels with Math.random stuff
        data: $("#frmManageUsers").serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.id) {
                // the controller action returned a JSON result with id property =>
                // handle it here
                alert('Sorry, an error occurred, successid: ' + data.id);
            } else {
                // The operation succeeded and the controller action returned a partial
                // view => update your DOM here
                $("#grid").html(data);
            }
        }),
        error: function (request, status, error) { ShowErrorMessage(); },
        complete: function () { hideProgress(); ShowSuccessMessage(); }
    });
}
```

Also notice that I have gotten rid of the `datatype: 'json',` parameter present in your request. This is wrong in 2 ways:

1. The correct property is called `dataType` instead of `datatype`
2. Since the controller action could return HTML or JSON (depending on whether the operation succeeds), we leave to jQuery to use the `Content-Type` response HTTP header set by the web server to automatically deduce the correct type and parse the `data` variable passed to your `success` callback.

Comment: Sir..Thanks you so much for quick and accurate answer.. and also for your advise on cache and url ...As you mentioned that url shouldn't be hardcoded..It should be generated by a server side helper.... what do u mean by that.. and how can achieve that..could you please help me out with this..with some example etc...Thanks once again for your help

Comment: I mean that you should be using the `Url.Action` helper on some of your DOM elements attributes that you could access in the `AddUser` action.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult AddUsers(Usertable model)
{
    var viewModel = new ReturnValue();

    int successid = ManageUserExecutor.Save(model);
    if (successid == -1)
    {
        viewModel.Message= "Failed"; 
        viewModel.ViewString = this.RenderViewToString("GridViewPartial", objList);
    }
    else
    {
        viewModel.Message= "Success";
        viewModel.ViewString = this.RenderViewToString("GridViewPartial");
    }
}
```

And use `data.ViewString` to access rendered partial view html.

```
$("#grid").html(data.ViewString);
```

And use `data.Message` for accessing the message you want.

```
$("#grid").html(data.Message);
```

You can find RenderViewToString function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string).